# Self-hosted Web API - Post Param null

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5

I'm trying to set up a simple test to make a POST request to my self-hosted Web-API server.

```
var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(new Uri(baseAddress));

// add a route
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "DefaultApi",
                            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);
server.OpenAsync().Wait();
```

I added a Controller:

```
public class PayloadController : ApiController
{    
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Hello from GET";
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage PostItem(Payload payload)
    {
        // payload 
        //...
    }
}
```

And I do have the corresponding model (making sure it contains properties):

```
public class Payload
    {
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string Command { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm using Rest Console on Chrome to test the server, getting correct results for the GET in my controller.

Issueing the following request as POST:

```
Request Url: http://localhost:8080/api/payload
Request Method: POST

Params: {
    "Date": "2012.09.26",
    "Command": "Hello"
}
```

EDIT: Content-Type is set to *application/json* and encoding to *UTF-8*

Setting a break-point at the controller shows that the POST params are not correctly deserialized into an `Paylod` object, the param is `null`.

What am I possibly missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the request Content-Type as `application/json`

**Edit**

Complete response with info from the comments below:

If you are using REST console's "request parameters" instead of "request payload raw body" it will not generate JSON out of them even when you specify `application/json`.

You need to paste raw JSON into the raw body field like this: http://screencast.com/t/iRWZqv91

```
{
    "Date": "2012.09.26",
    "Command": "Hello"
}
```

Comment: I actually did, plus Encoding is set to UTF-8.

Comment: if you are using REST console's "request parameters" instead of "request payload raw body" it will not generate JSON out of them. You need to paste raw JSON into the raw body field

Comment: That's what I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving a null post parameter to your controller you need to create a constructor with 0 parameters in your model.

Greetings